# HBase RegionServer: error telling master we are up

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am getting the following errors in the logs of the slave RegionServer.
The problem seems to be at

> regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty to
>   master=localhost,60000,1397430611631 with port=60020

The master is set as localhost but should actually be pointing towards master.
I am unable to figure out how the slave figures out who the master even after going through the docs.

The complete log is:

```
2014-04-14 04:49:35,939 INFO  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: CompactionChecker runs every 10sec
2014-04-14 04:49:35,950 INFO  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: reportForDuty to master=localhost,60000,1397430611631 with port=60020, startcode=1397431174733
2014-04-14 04:49:36,083 WARN  [regionserver60020] regionserver.HRegionServer: error telling master we are up
com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.RegionServerStatusProtos$RegionServerStatusService$BlockingStub.regionServerStartup(RegionServerStatusProtos.java:5402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.reportForDuty(HRegionServer.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:846)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClient.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClient.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.getConnection(RpcClient.java:1536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1654)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: your region server can not connect to master, so check if your master service has started up with jps.

Answer (score 0):

check your /etc/hosts file,if there is something like

> 127.0.0.1 localhost yourhost

change it to

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>   192.168.1.1  yourhost

Comment: This content should be in comment